# Fixing The Position Of A Table

Tags: html, css

I have a program that generates a static HTML file.  I have a list of links to sections of the file in a table. I want to be able to jump to a link or scroll the file and have the table stay fixed.  I have this code that works via CSS:

```
<table>
<tr><td><table><tr><td> <div style="position:fixed; top:50px; right:10px"> Table of    Contents Table</div> <td></tr>
<tr><td> <div style="position:fixed; top:65px; right:10px">Some Contents</div></tr>
<tr><td> <div style="position:fixed; top:80px; right:10px">Some More Contents</div>   </td></tr>
<tr><td><div style="position:fixed; top:95x; right:10px"> Even More Contents</div>   </td></tr>
</table>
```

I have this code that doesn't work.  If I wrap the style tags  around the entire table it locks the entire page and you can't scroll.  This happens even if I wrap the table in div tags.  Doing it this way is preferable since I don't have to play with the vertical offsets like I do when each row of the table has its own style tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
table#t-legend
{ position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 10px }
</style>

<div> <table id="t-legend">
<tr><td><table><tr><td> Fixed Contents Table</td></tr>
<tr><td> Some Contents</tr>
<tr><td> Some More Contents</td></tr>
<tr><td> Even More Contents</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pPQu2/3/
 Here note that i have removed the css for #t-legend and also check the markup. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks.  I may go with that approach and have the fixed links across the top and let the main table scroll underneath it

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid.

`<table id="t-legend">` has no matching closing tag, and there are some other unopened/unclosed tr,td,p tags.  Validating your html is always a good place to start.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pPQu2/5/ for working example.  I didn't fix all the bad html but the fixed position bit works.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for that.  The extra  table tag wasn't supposed to be there. I think I stared at that for an hour last night and never noticed it.  I know the fixed table would be stacked over the larger one, I was just trying to get the fixed bit working. :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what you meant so forgive me if i am wrong but I checked your jsfiddle page and if you want the page with your table to be scrollable just change the following in your css:

```
{ position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 10px }
```

to:

```
{ position: relative; top: 50px; left: 10px }
```

However this is a bit of a band-aid hack and i say this because some of the other members already pointed out that it is important to make sure you close your

```
<tr>
```

tag with

```
</tr>
```

and keep your td tags inside the tr tags and close them as well like so:

```
<tr><td> whatever u want here </td></tr>
```

As of now your table is not written well and wont validate ever. You should keep good habits when coding so that you can be COOLER like the rest of us. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your `<div>` tag:

```
<div> 
    <table id="t-legend">
        <tr><td><table><tr><td> Fixed Contents Table</td></tr>
        <tr><td> Some Contents</tr>
        <tr><td> Some More Contents</td></tr>
        <tr><td> Even More Contents</td></tr>
    </table>
<!-- close the tag here -->
</div>
```

Unclosed tags can cause all sorts of issues, try this and report back if your code still doesn't work.

Even better: recreate your issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Sorry. Not closing the div tag was a typo.  In the code it is closed. The div tag doesn't make a difference anyway. Whether it is there or not, the page still won't scroll. I recreated the issue at JSFiddle.  That is a handy site. If I don't include the code above for the fixed position table, the results window lets me scroll.  If I do include the code, the results window has no scroll bar.

Comment: @DavidGreen it'd be great if you could provide a link to your JS Fiddle

Comment: Here's the fiddle that won't scroll:   http://jsfiddle.net/pPQu2/  and here is a fiddle that will: http://jsfiddle.net/JuRXg/   The difference is the first table that is fixed with a CSS style.  I can either remove that table or remove the style tag and the page scrolls again.